# Export wizard error

Tags: android, dalvik

In Eclipse, when I first export my application to an android apk, the process succeeds. If I modify my code and try to re-export the app, I get the error "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1".
If I clear my project and then launch the export again, the app is correctly built.

What can be the cause of this strange behaviour?

The complete description of the error is below :

Message :
Export Wizard Error

```
Exception stack trace :
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:305)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:234)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:792)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:282)
    ... 4 more
```

Session data :

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_17
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Answer (score 1):

disable 'Build Automcatically' by Projects -> Build Automatically, then do a clean + build all. Let me know if you still face any problems

Comment: If I clean the project before rebuilding it completely, as said in my question, the build process works perfectly well. The problem is that I doesn't prevent me from finding the problem later again.

Comment: @Zelig63 So keep Build Automatically disabled?